# Create 1% Sample Using Multiprocessing in Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to process a large dataset (300GB, myfile.txt in the script) line by line using multiprocessing. I want to define a 1% random sample based one variable (contained in unique_ids_final.txt). My first step is to define the sample and then I want to read the data file using multiprocessing. I would like to improve the efficiency of the code in two ways:

First, I'd like to pass the pct1 object from the parent to the child so that it only needs to be defined once. I've seen a description of this on [thelaziestprogrammer.com: Pass Data to Workers w/o Globals](https://thelaziestprogrammer.com/python/multiprocessing-pool-expect-initret-proposal), but I'm relatively new to python and don't understand how to implement it in my code.

Second, I'd like to define the chunks without reading in the data. In `chunkify()` I get the start of each chunk and the number of bytes that need to be read by looking for the end of the line after reading in 1MB of data. I was hoping to use seek to move forward by 1MB and then find the end of the line, but this creates problems because later I need to read in the chunks and read treats `'\n'` as one byte, while seek treats it as two.

Any other suggestions to increase efficiency would also be much appreciated!

```
#define sample
uid = list(line.strip() for line in open('Subsets/unique_ids_final.txt'))
pct1 = round(len(uid)/100)
random.seed(1)
id_pct1 = set(random.sample(uid, k=pct1))
id_pct1.add(vname)

#read original file and write 1% sample using multiprocessing
def worker(chunkStart, chunkSize, q):
    with open('myfile.txt') as f:
        tlines = []
        f.seek(chunkStart)
        lines = f.read(chunkSize).splitlines()
        for line in lines:
            data = line.split('*')
            if data[30] in id_pct1: tlines.append(line)
        q.put(tlines)
        return tlines

def chunkify(fname,size=1024*1024):
    fileEnd = os.path.getsize(fname)
    with open(fname, 'r') as f:
        chunkEnd2 = 0
        while True:
            chunkStart = chunkEnd2
            f.seek(chunkStart)
            f.read(size)
            chunkEnd1 = f.tell()
            f.readline()
            chunkEnd2 = f.tell()
            chunkSz = 1024*1024 + chunkEnd2 - chunkEnd1 - 1
            yield chunkStart, chunkSz
            if chunkEnd2 >= fileEnd:
                break

def listener(q):
    with open('myfile1pct.txt', 'w') as out_f1:
        while True:
            m = q.get()
            if m == 'kill': break
            else:
                for line in m:
                    out_f1.write(line+'\n')
                    out_f1.flush()

def main():

    manager = mp.Manager()
    q = manager.Queue()
    pool = mp.Pool()

    watcher = pool.apply_async(listener, (q,))

    jobs = []
    for chunkStart, chunkSize in chunkify('myfile.txt'):
        jobs.append(pool.apply_async(worker,(chunkStart,chunkSize,q)))

    for job in jobs:
        job.get()

    q.put('kill')
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Can you share some information about the data itself? Ideally we would have enough to run the program, since matters of performance are so dependent on benchmarking and profiling.

Comment: It is insurance claims data, which is privacy protected so I don't know of any sample data that's out there. There are ~300 million lines in the file. Each line represents a claim line and has 171 variables that are delimited with *. I make the 1% sample at the person level, using a list of 4 million person ids represented by integers and contained in idunique_ids_final. Let me know if there's any other useful information I can share.

Comment: The 4 million individual IDs are used to determine which claims to extract?

Comment: Yes, a 1% sample of the 4 million IDs. So I'm extracting the claims for 40,000 people.

Comment: I somehow forgot about this question, but I will return to it...

Comment: @giacomo1488 Could you share some more context about the problem you're trying to solve? It sounds like you want to create a 1% sample based on one variable in each line? Does that mean you only care about 2 fields in every line-- one for ID and the other for the variable you measuring against? It really sounds like a Python script is not the best tool for this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disclaimer: I have never worked with `multiprocessing`, so I can't comment on that implementation.

---

## Handling Files

I noticed at the top of the file you open a file, but never close it. (For the argument that an anonymous file is closed right after the statement is executed, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38660881/8968906) post). Leaving files open is [not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25070939/8968906). You should always close your files; leaving files open can slow down your program. I'd change that line to the code below:

```
with open('Subsets/unique_ids_final.txt') as file:
    uid = list(line.strip() for line in file.readlines())
```

While it is more typing, `with` automatically closes the file after the inner code is run.

## List Comprehension

A couple of you `for` loops can be reduced to one line statements. You can create a list directly with a `for` loop. Take a look:

```
tlines = [line for line in lines if line.split('*')[30] in id_pct1]
```

Same with `jobs`:

```
jobs = [
    pool.apply_async(worker, (chunk_start, chunk_size, q))
    for chunk_start, chunk_size in chunkify('myfile.txt')
]
```

## One line `if` statements

This

```
if m == 'kill': break
```

should be this

```
if m == 'kill':
    break
```

Even though it's one line, *one word*, you should still indent.

## Docstrings

You should include docstrings when you write functions, methods, and classes. They are used to provide more description. Take a look:

```
def worker(chunk_start, chunk_size, q) -> List[str]:
    """
    Read original file and write 1% sample using multiprocessing

    :param <type> chunk_start: <description>
    :param <type> chunk_size: <description>
    :param <type> q: <description>

    :return: List[str]
    """
```

I had trouble following your code and understanding what variables were what types. Essentially, when labeling parameters in your docstrings, the format I used goes as follows:

```
:param <type of parameter> <name of parameter>: <description about parameter>
```

And returns are as follows:

```
:return: <type to return>
```

If you want docbuilders, consider using [`sphinx`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/).

## Type Hints

These help portray what types are accepted and returned by a function/method. Take a look:

```
def add(x: int, y: int) -> int:
    return x + y
```

While this is a very straightforward example, the idea is still there.

## Variable/Parameter Names

These should be in `snake_case`, not `mixedCase`.

```
chunkStart -> chunk_start
chunkSize -> chunk_size
```